# Reflection Casting and Overloaded Method Dispatching in Java

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

Note that all the code is a simplified example in order to only communicate the core ideas of my question. It should all compile and run though, after slight editing.

I have several classes which all implement a common interface.

```
public interface Inter{}
public class Inter1 implements Inter{}
public class Inter2 implements Inter{}
```

In a separate class I have a list of type Inter, which I use to store and remove Inter1 and Inter2 types, based on user input.

```
java.util.ArrayList<Inter> inters = new java.util.ArrayList<Inter>();
```

I also have a family of overloaded methods, which deal with how each implementation interacts with each other, along with a default implementation for 2 "Inter"s.

```
void doSomething(Inter in1, Inter in2){
    System.out.println("Inter/Inter");     
}
void doSomething(Inter1 in1, Inter1 in2){
    System.out.println("Inter1/Inter11");    
}
void doSomething(Inter2 in1, Inter1 in2){
    System.out.println("Inter2/Inter1");    
}
```

The methods are periodically called like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < inters.size() - 1; i++){
    for(int o = i+1; o < inters.size(); o++){
        Inter in1 = inters.get(i);    Inter in2 = inters.get(o);

        doSomething(in1.getClass().cast(in1), in2.getClass().cast(in2));

        System.out.println("Class 1: " + in1.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Class 2: " + in2.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

An example output from this is:

```
Inter/Inter
Class 1: Inter
Class 2: Inter
Inter/Inter
Class 1: Inter
Class 2: Inter1
Inter/Inter
Class 1: Inter1
Class 2: Inter1
```

Looking at the output, it is clear that doSomething(Inter in1, Inter in2) is called, even in cases when other methods should be called. Interestingly, the class names outputted are the correct ones.

Why does java have static method overloading when the class types are determined at runtime using reflection?
Is there any way to get Java to do this? I know I can use reflection and Class.getMethod() and method.invoke() to get the results I want, but it would be so much neater to do so with casting.

I realize that questions about similar concepts have been asked before, but while all of the answers were informative, none satisfied me.
Double dispatch looked like it would work, but that would mean reworking a lot of code, since I use this type of thing often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like we're talking about what's going on with:

```
doSomething(in1.getClass().cast(in1), in2.getClass().cast(in2));
```

Based on your surprise that the type that is being output is always `Inter`, it seems you're a little confused on what's going on here.  In particular, you seem to think that `in1.getClass().cast(in1)` and `in2.getClass().cast(in2)` should be forcing a different overload because of their differing runtime type.  However, this is wrong.

Method overload resolution happens statically.  This means that it happens based on the declared types of the two arguments to the method.  Since both `in1` and `in2` are both declared as `Inter`, the method chosen is obviously `void doSomething(Inter in1, Inter in2)`.

The takeaway here is that `in1` is declared as an `Inter`.  This means that `in1.getClass()` is essentially the same as `Inter.class` for the purposes of static analysis -- `getClass` simply returns a `Class<? extends Inter>`.  Therefore, the casts are useless, and you're only ever going to get the first overload.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that wasn't the case because its rather annoying. I just can't help but feel like stuff like this should be dynamic. It makes everything so much more complicated... Oh well, I guess I'll just have to use the reflection API, as messy as it looks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (JLS) in section 15.12 [Method Invocation Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) explains in detail the process that the compiler follows to choose the right method to invoke.

There, you will notice that this is a *compile-time* task. The JLS says in subsection 15.12.2:

> This step uses the **name of the method** and **the types of the argument expressions** 
>   to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable
>   There may be more than one such method, in which case the most specific one is chosen.

In your case, this means that since you are passing two objects of type `Integer`, the most specific method is the one that receives exactly that.

To verify the compile-time nature of this, you can do the following test.

Declare a class like this and compile it.

```
public class ChooseMethod {
   public void doSomething(Number n){
    System.out.println("Number");
   }
}
```

Declare a second class that invokes a method of the first one and compile it.

```
public class MethodChooser {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChooseMethod m = new ChooseMethod();
    m.doSomething(10);
   }
}
```

If  you invoke the main, the output says `Number`.

Now, add a second more specific method to the `ChooseMethod` class, and recompile it (but do not recompile the other class).

```
public void doSomething(Integer i) {
 System.out.println("Integer");
}
```

If you run the main again, the output is still `Number`.

Basically, because it was decided at compile time. If you recompile the `MethodChooser` class (the one with the main), and run the program again, the output will be `Integer`.

As such, if you want to force the selection of one of the overloaded methods, the type of the arguments must correspond with the type of the parameters at compile time, and not only at run time as you seem to expect in this exercise.